# Is there a way to print/list deprecated functions or hooks in use to the screen?

Tags: deprecation

As the title reads, is there a way to output to screen the list of deprecated functions and hooks that may be use as well as the location of these? For example, in reviewing the hooks in use in a site I've inherited, I came across `add_filter( 'rest_enabled', '__return_false' );` which has been deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

You can explore this https://gist.github.com/jbuchbinder/7419000

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/deprecated.php

Deprecated functions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Category:Deprecated_Functions